# Hibernate multimapping - map tables to one entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, hql

I have a spring boot application and use hibernate to load entities from PostgreSQL DB. I have a lot of tables with the same structure (columns: TIMESTAMP timestamp, DOUBLE ask, DOUBLE ask_vol, DOUBLE bid, DOUBLE bid_vol). For all this tables I use one entity Pair:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table
public class Pair implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String name;
@Id
@Column(name = "timestamp", nullable = false)
private Timestamp timestamp;
@Basic
@Column(name = "ask", nullable = true, precision = 6)
private double askPrice;
@Basic
@Column(name = "bid", nullable = true, precision = 6)
private double bidPrice;
@Basic
@Column(name = "vol_ask", nullable = true, precision = 4)
private double askVolume;
@Basic
@Column(name = "vol_bid", nullable = true, precision = 4)
private double bidVolume; }
```

The Pair.name is connected to the table's name. That's why all tables have different names and one entity.

In DAO I load the data like (for example get all row from the table with the name "pairName"):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public Collection<Pair> getAllPairs(String pairName){
    String hql = String.format("FROM %s ", pairName);
    return (List<Pair>) entityManager.createQuery(hql.toLowerCase()).getResultList();
}
```

For mapping table name I can use annotation @SecondaryTables, but the number of tables quite big. How can I say to Hibernate to map all the tables to one entity? P.S. I have also the ENUM with all table names. Thanks a lot

Comment: Not answering the exact question, but if you are only reading you can create a view with an union on all the tables and the table name in a first column and map that view instead. Then you'll be able to query the view to get what you need.

Comment: Does the database system support table structure inheritance (postgres use of the inherit for example)?

Comment: @PeterRader yes, sure